# What do the green bars next to players' names in the 'tab' window mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I push <kbd>TAB</kbd> on Minecraft servers it comes up with a little green connection bar next to the players' names!

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 14):

It represents how good each player's latency (ping) to the server is. The fuller the bars, the lower (and better) the latency.

Answer (score 8):

The green bars represent the strength of a player's connection to the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "strength"?

Comment: It means how strong it is.

Answer (score -2):

It's The Players Internet connection, Its How Fast The Players Internet is, When its full its fast... When its low its slow,

Comment: Eeeeh...it's the player's connection _to the server_, not their internet connection. Just nitpicking though! :)

Answer (score -4):

It's the player's internet connection, it's like a WIFI bar; it describes what players are 
online.